# Why is this Apache Spark line causing an OutOfMemoryException (GC overhead limit exceeded)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I understand that this exception means the executor has run out of memory.  I have applied `--executor-memory 4096m`, and I am not caching or persisting any of the RDDs in this program.  And yet it still occurs, so I think I must be doing something wrong.  The line that always triggers the problem is:

```
    val linksIn = rootSet.join(reverseLinks).mapValues(x => x._2)
```

where `rootSet` is an RDD of 449 (Long, String) pairs, and `reverseLinks` is an RDD of 130 million (Long, Long) pairs.  I would expect the resulting join to contain a few tens of thousands of pairs, at most.

Possibly of interest: `reverseLinks` was made by swapping the forward links, i.e. `reverseLinks = links.map(x => x.swap)`, and I was able to do the exact same join with the forward links with no problem.  Possibly the statistics of the reversed links are different, but it shouldn't be outrageous.

Am I doing something wrong here?  Is there a more efficient way to find the subset of items in my `reverseLinks` RDD that match keys in my root set?  If not, what can be done to avoid this error and allow the computation to finish?

Comment: Because `RDD.join` is realized through `cogroup` ‒ any large group on any side will cause memory issues. Consider switching to `DataFrame` API, which uses more conservative approach.